# Two different databases, sth which are wanted are mixed. I could not get over it. PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

this is really hard question. I have an exam. And questions will be like that. They are really hard. These are my database:

```
director (martinscorsese, american, 1, 51).

director (hayaomiyazaki, japanese, 1, 23).

director (stevenspielberg, american, 3, 49).

director (georgelucas, american, 0, 19).

director (christophernolan, american, 0, 10).

watched(departed, [george, jane, eric]).

watched(theaviator, [jane,eric]).

watched(swrevengeofthesith, [paul,eric]).

watched(transformers, [paul, george, jane]).
```

I want to implement the predicate `audiance(A,N,O,L1)` that returns the list of all movies (`L1`) not yet seen by anyone in `A`, which has been directed by a director of Nationality `N` who won at least `O` oscars. The list `L` must not contain any duplicates.

```
audiance([paul],american,1,X). returns X=[ departed, theaviator ]

audiance([paul,george],N,0,X). returns N=american X= [theaviator]

audiance(X,american,0,[swrevengeofthesith]). returns X=[jane,george]

audiance([paul,george,jane],N,0,X). returns false
```

plz help me :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i could just post code but i dont think it would help to pass the exam

you should divide the problem into smaller and easier sub-problems.

1) a predicate not_seen(Movie,People) that returns true only if nobody in the list People have seen the Movie

2) a predicate director_nationality(Movie, Nationality) that returns true if the director of the Movie has the given nationality

3) a predicate director_oscars(Director, Num_Oscars) that returns true if the director has won at least Num_Oscars oscars

then you have to combine all these in one predicate which you can call movie_requirements(Movie).

finally, to find all the movies you can use [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3)
to ensure that there wont be any doublicates you could use [sort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) that will remove any duplicates or use bagof/3 instead of findall/3

check member/2 and the other built-in predicates for lists